Different shaped responses for generate_presigned_post
My application's deployed across 2 regions, and calling generate_presigned_post from the two regions returns different response shapes.  The first returns:
{
    "url": "https://app-1-test-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/",
    "key": "boo",
    "fields": {
        "key": "boo",
        "x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
        "x-amz-credential": "ASIA.../20240424/eu-west-3/s3/aws4_request",
        "x-amz-date": "20240424T131803Z",
        "x-amz-security-token": "...",
        "policy": "...",
        "x-amz-signature": "..."
    }
}

The other returns:
{
    "url": "https://app-2-test-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/",
    "key": "boo",
    "fields": {
        "key": "boo",
        "AWSAccessKeyId": "ASI...XU",
        "x-amz-security-token": "...",
        "policy": "...",
        "signature": "..."
    }
}

Why would these be different?  Is there a way to keep them constant?  The docs seem to indicate that just about anything can be returned for fields, and don't explain how this is controlled.

It might be to do with Sigv2 vs Sigv4. "Amazon S3 supports Signature Version 4, a protocol for authenticating inbound API requests to AWS services, in all AWS Regions. At this time, AWS Regions created before January 30, 2014 will continue to support the previous protocol, Signature Version 2. Any new Regions after January 30, 2014 will support only Signature Version 4 and therefore all requests to those Regions must be made with Signature Version 4." It's possible the pre-signed URLs are still using Sigv2 in some regions?
